# Removing a staged AppxPackage

Tags: powershell, windows-store-app

On Windows Enterprise 10.19044.1708 21H2, I'm trying to use `Remove-AppxPackage` PowerShell cmdlet to uninstall the Microsoft 3D Viewer app.

I have it down to the point where it's no longer showing as "Installed" with `Get-AppxPackage`, only as "Staged" -- however, for my purposes, I *need* it not even to be staged.

I have tried both with and without `-AllUsers`, *both* on the `Remove-AppxPackage` *and* the `Get-AppxPackage` side of the pipe, but it's still not removing it *entirely* as it's still showing as Staged for user `S-1-15-18`. (It should go without saying that I *am* launching PowerShell via the "Run as Administrator" option.)

Does anyone know how to "unstage" a Windows Store package?

---

Windows Store itself is disabled via Group Policy, so there's no worry of a user opening the Store up and accidentally re-staging it when it refreshes the database.

Comment: `S-1-15-18` is the network service account. What is the exact command you are running?

Answer (score 3):

To uninstall a staged App Package, you use the
[Remove-AppxPackage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/remove-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
PowerShell cmdlet as the System user.

Sysinternals has a tool that allows you to do this:
[psexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).

For example, to remove of all of them, run in an elevated command prompt
(not powershell) the following command:

```
psexec -s powershell -c "get-appxpackage | remove-appxpackage"
```

(But I suggest being more selective.)

Comment: Is it possible to do this without 3rd-party software?

Comment: Psexec belongs to Microsoft.

Comment: You can do it with a scheduled task running as `SYSTEM` too (trivial). Wonder why MS doesn't just make psexec native in the OS since they own it though. The psexec logic is much simpler, but I believe I've done it before that way too.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know how to "unstage" a Windows Store package?

If you run `Get-AppxPackage *3DViewer* | Remove-AppxPackage` as the built-in local Administrator the application should be properly removed.

> (It should go without saying that I am launching PowerShell via the "Run as Administrator" option.)

This apparently isn’t enough. The command must be ram as the built-in Administrator user, which is disabled by default, its necessary to use this use due to the differences to a user created Administrator user.

Answer (score 1):

I had some success (not all staged apps were uninstallable this way, but some) with a command like that as privileged user:

```
Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -online | % {if ($_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft.YourPhone") {$_}} | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online
```

(found at https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-remove-windows-8-apps-before-you-run-sysprep/)